# Tomcat 7.0.35 OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: tomcat

I deployed a pretty big maven project to tomcat, and now whenever I try and hit up localhost:8080 tomcat gives me an OutOfMemeroryError. It seems to have no problems until I try and check out localhost:8080 in a browser. I added an environmental variable for JAVA_OPS allowing up to 4096m, configured catalina.sh to do the same, and same deal with startup.bat. I need to proceed past this, what do?

Comment: try setting in setenv.sh. CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

Comment: I didn't have a setenv.sh script so I added one to tomcat/bin and it says: 

  JRE_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

Comment: Nothing changed. Error persists.

Answer (score 1):

I started reviewing my changes, and I changed the environmental variable from JAVA_OPS to JAVA_OPTS, and added another variable for CATALINA_OPTS with the same data. It worked.

Comment: You only need CATALINA_OPTS. JAVA_OPTS will also be used for the command to shut down your tomcat, which barely needs any resources. especially no PermGen of 1G - you should be on the safe side by just configuring CATALINA_OPTS (having the same in JAVA_OPTS will configure the same values twice - if they differ, I don't know which ones will have precedence)